# Angularjs 1.5.5 with @Component decorator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I am having a hard time finding a good code example of component using Angularjs 1.5.5 ( **NOT Angular 2.0** ). Does Angular 1.5.5 really supports decorators like @Component OR @Injectable and if yes can someone please share a good code example ?

Also i would like to know how does the inter component communicaton works in Angular 1.5.5 ? Does it have @Input decorator ?

Comment: Decorators are TS feature, they are not used in Angular 1.5.5. Components are supported, dependency injection is supported (obviously). Inputs and outputs works the same, although the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a transpiler (babel or TS) you can use ng-decorated which provide angular 2 syntax for angular 1.5 components. It works with @Inject/Service/Input/Output/etc

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me an example of that, any plnkr, blog, etc.